# Masking arrays in Java as with numpy in python

Tags: java, python, arrays, numpy

Is there an elegant way to select elements of an array in Java similar to Numpy in Python?

```
mask = np.array([True, False, False, True])
myArray = np.array([4, 3, 1, 2])
result = myArray[mask]
print(result)
```

This will give me
    [4, 2]

Now I want to do the same in Java (without having to write many lines of code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a built-in mechanism in Java, the array utility classes don't have it either.

```
int[] array = {4, 3, 1, 2};
boolean[] mask = {true, false, false, true};

int[] result = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                        .filter(i -> mask[i])
                        .map(i -> array[i])
                        .toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works and is reasonable in scope! Still sad that there is no more elegant way to do this in Java...